# Changing Colour of button when clicked - Windows Phone VB

Tags: vb.net, colors, windows-phone-8.1

how can i change the colour of a button when it is pressed in Windows Phone non Silverlight?

I am working with VB, i have had a look online how to do this, but almost all of the answers are in C#.

I tried translating C# into VB, but have not be able to get it to work.

Do you have to do it in the XAML? or in the Code itself?

```
Imports Windows.UI.Colors
  button2.Background = New Brush(Windows.UI.Colors.White)
```

The "Brush" Part is there the problem is at.

Comment: show us what code you have tried and what the errors/unwanted results were... then we can help

Comment: opps, my bad, this is what i have.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer after playing around with it.

For anyone else that wants to know here is the codes.

`Imports Windows.UI.Color
 button1.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green)`